# Orchard CMS Navigation Menu Item in new window

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

I just want to know how can I open menu items in new windows/tabs in Orchard CMS, using Advanced Menu Navigation. 
Yes I know how to use Crtl, or Right Click,
I just want to learn how my customers can select it while creating a menu item, options like "show as link". If there is no quick solution, how can I achieve it? Custom Css?

Thanks in advance,
Murat Duman.

Answer (score 1):

Is it for the Admin or the end user? If for the end user, you can change the code to open the links in the new window ( target = _blank)

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below as an "Html Menu Item" on the navigation page.

```
<a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a>
```